# How to write the code to test if three rows of a dataset can be the sides of a triangle in R

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to programming, and I have a problem. I would appreciate any help.
The problem is this:
I have a file that contains 146,610 rows of numbers, with three positive numbers in each row (three columns). For each row, I have to determine if the three numbers can be the sides of a triangle. For each row, I want the program to return 0 or 1, where 0 means "not a triangle" and 1 means "it is a triangle". I want these values in a vector that is called `isTriangle` that I will use for the next part of the problem.
This is my code so far, but I know it is completely wrong. Please guide me the right way.

```
triangles <- read.csv(filename, header = FALSE, col.names = c("a", "b", "c"))
for(i in 1:nrow(triangles)) {
  if (triangles$a + triangles$b > triangles$c 
      || triangles$a + triangles$c > triangles$b ||
      triangles$c + triangles$b > triangles $a) {
```

[The first few lines of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjyVz.png)

Comment: You're on the right track. Review the `ifelse()` function and put your three `or` statements into the first argument of the `ifelse`, and fill out the rest as you need it. This is a pretty good first question to StackOverflow but next time, some data would be helpful for others to help. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(10652.06,5066.678,255.2218,301.0861,8907.806,2471.524,10824.15),
           b = c(4054.905,1631.475,9935.731,2607.451,1605.074,6580.303,4374.1),
           c = c(6070.151,3002.47,10338.6,3853.397,6465.37,4020.112,5512.144
                 ))
triangles <- df
for(i in 1:nrow(triangles)) {
  if(triangles$a[i] + triangles$b[i] > triangles$c[i] 
     & triangles$a[i] + triangles$c[i] > triangles$b[i] &
     triangles$c[i] + triangles$b[i] > triangles$a[i]){
    triangles$isTriangle[i] <- 1
  }else{
    triangles$isTriangle[i] <- 0
  }
}
# solution
         a        b         c isTriangle
1 10652.0600 4054.905  6070.151          0
2  5066.6780 1631.475  3002.470          0
3   255.2218 9935.731 10338.600          0
4   301.0861 2607.451  3853.397          0
5  8907.8060 1605.074  6465.370          0
6  2471.5240 6580.303  4020.112          0
7 10824.1500 4374.100  5512.144          0
```

you did everything correct other than `||`, you have to use `&` instead. i hope this helps

Comment: can you please provide some data?

Comment: check ``length(triangle$isTriangle)``

Comment: Yes, I added an image of the first few lines of the dataset to the question. I hope that helps. The code actually worked, but I don't think it is saving the values into the vector correctly. I am not sure.

Comment: It worked! I didn't want `isTriangle` to be saved to the dataframe as a new variable, so instead of `triangles$isTriangle` I put 'isTriangle' because before making the for loop, I assigned an empty vector called 'isTriangle' like this: `isTriangle = c()`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a explicit `for` loop for most things in R.

```
triangles <- transform(triangles, 
                       result = as.integer(a + b > c | a + c > b | c + b > a))
```

`as.integer` would change the logical values to integer values.